# How to create clickable phone number

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Outside of a UIWebView, how can I make a phone number clickable that is in say a UILabel or UIButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code to enable call from your application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://0123456789"]];
```

Comment: Thanks.  If your text is in the title of a navigation bar or prompt of the navigation bar, how can it be made click able?

Comment: Hi, 4th take one UIView and take a UIButton inside the UIView
and set that UIView as a titleView of the UINavigationBar.and put the call event on that button event...i think you understand what i am trying to say...

Comment: any suggestions on how to addd same feature using Handsoff in iOS8 ?

Answer (score 1):

make a UIButton of custom type and as Caption set a number to display... so it will display only one number (button won't be visible...) and on button's click event Call that particular number by

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1456987452"]];
```